# Iterating through polymorphic array is not catching all descendent classes

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have an ArrayList that I am storing a variety of descendent classes (i.e., memo, todo, phone).  Item is an interface that includes a print method.  I am attempting to iterate through the Item array and print each todo Item for a specific date, a previous date and a future date.  When I do so, even though the logic seems sound it never prints the previous date - only the current and future dates.  Please see the code below:

```
public class itemStore {
    List<Item> itemArray;

    public itemStore() {
        itemArray = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void printTodoDate(String date, String prev, String future){
        for (Item todo : itemArray){
            if (date.equals(((Todo) todo).getDate()) || prev.equals(((Todo) todo).getDate()) || future.equals(((Todo) todo).getDate())) {
                ((Todo) todo).print();
            }
        }
    }

public class Todo extends Item {
    String message;
    String date;

}
```

Example output:

Command? list
todo: 23/2/2000 this is a todo
todo: 22/2/2000 todo again
todo: 24/2/2000 another one yeah

It is falling down at the printTodoDate - dates are all working fine.

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? In the code you provided there is nothing that could case the problem. Btw. why are you casting every `Item` to `Todo`? `Item` interface should have a `print` and `getDate` method specified so you won't have to cast anything - that way your code would be much more readable.

Comment: Ah.  That helps.  Thank you.  I finally figured out how to debug with user input.  The issue was to do with the previous.equals portion (method that returns this value - I had the wrong month).  Regarding the Item interface - there are a number of descendents of the Item interface that don't require dates; that's why I haven't included the getDate in the Item interface.  Anyway, thanks for your assistance - I'll be sure to debug next time.